# How to call onclick listener from another window in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to call my Java method from listener that is located under separate view/modal window and execute it. This way I would use my method without rewriting code. This is neccesary for me because in some circumstances, I can't get same results. So I would like to invoke onclick methods from separate modal window. How can be this done in Vaadin? I would need example code, really don't know how to do this?

Comment: It can be done, just take hold of a reference to the object where you wish to fire the click event. But without any code it's difficult to explain...

Comment: Any example you may give?

Comment: Show your code, passing references isn't that difficult in java

Comment: I don't know how to do it because 10 files in invovled and I do this for my company and I'm not allowed to make this code public. Isn't there any simple example how to do it?

Comment: You could boil it down to two-3 classes which show the relevant case

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hold a reference to the object you want to call its method. but a better way to do that is using an interface and pass the object using that.

```
 public interface A {

      public void theMethod ();
}

class B  implements A {

     public void theMethod (){
          //do something here 
     }
}
```

you can pass a reference of B to the class that hold listener and from there you can call the theMethod you want to call.

```
class YourWindow(){

    private A theInstance;

    yourWindow(A instance)
     {
         theInstance = instance;
     }   

      ...
    void onClick(){
       ...
       theInstance.theMethod();
       ... 
   }
```

I suggest you study design patterns.

> Design patterns represent the best practices used by experienced
>   object-oriented software developers. Design patterns are solutions to
>   general problems that software developers faced during software
>   development. These solutions were obtained by trial and error by
>   numerous software developers over quite a substantial period of time.

using Mediator and Observer is very helpful in such situation.